# In search of a literature or theory that deals with $\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx \geq \int_{g([a,b])}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

I stumble upon the following problem. Given an increasing function $g$ is there a function $f$ (not identically null) s.t.

$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx \geq \int_{g([a,b])}f(x)dx$$

And, if there is, what can we say about $f$. The problem could be reinstated in terms of pushforward, i.e. find a signed measure $\mu$ s.t. $\mu([a,b]) \geq g_{*}(\mu)([a,b])$. There are also other analogous ways to approach it (in terms of differential equation the problem is a composition of function). However, none of this seems to shed light upon the problem. I tried to find a theory of some sort that could help me with it, but so far have not been successful.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Considering avs answer the following idea emerged. Let $g$ be a strictly increasing continuouosly differentiable function. Let $A = \{x : g'(x) < 1\}$ and $B = \{x : g'(x) > 1\}$. Then $g$ is a contraction in every open interval in $A$ (actually, a subcontraction) and is an expansion (in the sense that its inverse is a contraction) in every open interval in $B$. Thus let $f$ be s.t. $f \leq 0$ in A, $f \geq 0$ in $B$ and $f = 0$ in $(A \cup B)^c$. Then $f$ must be a solution.

Comment: Perhaps this, and the associated inequalities may be interesting:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_decreasing_rearrangement

Answer (score 1):

A simple experiment gives a less than encouraging result: let
$$
g(x) = 2x, \quad a = 0, \quad b > 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
g([a, b]) = g([0, b]) = [0, 2b].
$$

Now imagine a measure $\mu$ on the (Borel $\sigma$-algebra of) $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the required inequality.  Then we would need to have
$$
\mu([0, b]) \geq \mu ( g ([0, b]) ) = \mu([0, 2b]) = \mu([0, b]) + \mu(]b, 2b]),
$$
which would imply that
$$
\mu\left(]b, 2b]\right) = 0 \mbox{ for all positive }b.
$$
Thus, the existence of a measure $\mu$ with the desired property (a, sort of, "monotonicity w.r.t. $g$") depends a lot on what $g$ is.

If $g$ is a simple contraction, e.g., $g(x) = x / 2$, then it is not hard to show that $\mu$ can be taken to be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

It's also not that hard to construct a $\mu$ that will fail the desired property for the latter $g$; e.g., let $\mu$ have the density function
$$
f(x) = {C \over 1 + x^2}, \quad \mbox{where $C$ is large enough}.
$$
Basically, $f(x)$ assigns large measures to subsets near $0$, and small ones far away from $0$, but $g$ takes subsets that are far from $0$ and brings them closer to $0$, thus increasing their measure.

If you are looking for the field of mathematics that studies this, I'd try to [look at measures as linear functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).  The general concept of monotonicity of functionals (which are generally not in a Euclidean field, hence devoid of a "natural" linear ordering) is usually developed by [using the concept of a cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space).

Comment: I believe you manage to show that in case $g(x) = 2x$ then $f$ cannot be non-negative. My analogy with measure was misleading. The first problem that I mentioned gives no restriction to $f$.

Comment: Now I notice that this implies, just as in the case $g$ is a contraction $f \equiv 1$ is a solution, that in the case $g$ is an expansion $f \equiv -1$ is a solution.

Comment: Cool. So, if we at least require $f$ to be locally integrable, then perhaps we can replace "measure" by "signed measure"?